# C programming, reading from file error?

Tags: c, file, pointers

My code is not putting the text file data into `line` on the second pass of the `while` loop, and any subsequent pass. I'm sure it's a silly error but I cannot find it.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 FILE *fr;
 char *line,*word,*vali;
 ssize_t read;
 int i=0,sum=0,len =0,flag=0;
 const char delim[2]=" ";


 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {

     line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&len)); 
     word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&len));
     vali = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&len));

     fr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
     if(fr==NULL)
     {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fr)) != -1)
     {
         printf("line is %s\n", line );
         fscanf(fr,"%s%*[^\n]",word);           

         printf("%s ", word);
         vali=strtok(line, delim);
         while(vali != NULL)
         {
             sum=sum+atoi(vali);
             vali = strtok(NULL, delim);
         }
         printf("%d\n", sum);
         sum=0;
         vali=" ";
         len = strlen(line);
    }
    fclose(fr);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(&len))`. This doesn't look correct. What is `len`? It looks like you are allocating space for a pointer only.

Comment: What `len` is defined as and initialized as?

Comment: Show the full program along with the contents of the file. Also, indent the code properly.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: What are `len`, `line`, `word`, `vali` defined as? We could assume something and fix but, thats not the way this works. Please make sure that you put the code that can be compiled.

Comment: The code compiles, at the moment len is just the length of the first line, which should be plenty of space for everything else

Comment: see [getline](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: @BarneyChambers: your code as displayed in your question does not compile, it lacks the declaration of `line`, `word`, `vali` and `len`.

Comment: Apologies, added those declarations in now

Comment: @BarneyChambers: BLUPIXY's comment contains a link with a working example. You should look at that.

Comment: `getline(&line, &len, fr)`, In 2nd argument you need to give the size of the `line` but, you give 0. then how it store the line from the file.

Answer (score 2):

If len is some integral type containing the desired length of the first line, then:

```
    &len
```

Has type pointer-to-integer, and

```
    sizeof(&len)
```

Returns the size of a pointer (8 bytes on most 64 bit systems) and

```
    malloc(sizeof(&len))
```

Allocates only 8 bytes of memory (or whatever pointer size is on your system).

This is probably at least part of the issue.